# injective map between set of subfields and set of endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

In Theorem 8.4 of Basic Algebra by Jacobson we have the following map $$\psi:\Sigma\rightarrow \Gamma: F\mapsto \text{End}_FE$$ where $\Sigma$ is the set of all subfields of  a field $E$ and $\Gamma$ the set of subrings of the ring of endomorphisms of the additive group of E.

How do we show that it is an injective map?

Answer (score 1):

An element $x\in E$ is fixed by $End_FE$ if and only if $x\in F$. To see this, remark that $x\in F$, by definition the result is true, thus $F\subset Fix(End_F(E))$.

On the other hand, lrt $x\in Fix(End_F)$, suppose that $x$ is not in $F$, you can find a basis $(x,(y_i)_{i\in I})$ of the $F$-vector space $E$. Let $c\in F\neq 1$, you can define $f(x)=cx, f(y_i)=y_i$, it is an $F$-endomorphism of $E$ such that $f(x)\neq x$. Contradiction.

We deduce that $End_FE=End_{F'}E$ implies that $F=Fix(End_FE)=Fix(End_{F'}E)=F'$.

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed by $\text{End}_FE$"? I don't see why your first affirmation is correct. If I take $\phi\in\text{End}_FE, x\in F$ then $\phi(x) = \phi(x\cdot 1) = x\phi(1)$ and there is no reason $\phi(1)$ should be 1 that I can see.